# Как можно сгенерировать случайною строку с 16-символо (только цифры) значное число c#

Tags: c#

Как сгенерировать 16-ти значною строку например: XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону LINQ и Random

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static Random random = new Random();
public static string RandomString(int length)
{
    const string chars = "0123456789";
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
      .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}
```

код найден по запросу "random digit string c#"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1344242/4423545